# Google cloud sdk version 370.0.0-0 won't install on raspberry pi

Tags: google-cloud-sdk

I ran a routine apt upgrade on my RPi running Raspbian (Debian) version 10.11.  This upgraded google-cloud-sdk from version 369 to version 370.  The upgrade failed with

```
/usr/bin/gcloud: 190: exec: /usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/bundledpythonunix/bin/python3: Exec format error
```

I uninstalled google-cloud-sdk and reinstalled, same error.
I explicitly installed version 369 and I'm back up.

I'm mostly posting this so that perhaps someone at Google will see and fix this. Or not.  I'm happy staying on version 369 for now.

Comment: Possibly related: https://issuetracker.google.com/216325949 and https://groups.google.com/g/google-cloud-dev/c/LpfiekOSwrw . Note that bugs are better reported in the issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks much!  This is clearly the same bug.   I'll be sure to use issue tracker next time.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a broken installer by google. A workaround is use CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable to point installed python3 such as

`export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3.9`